# loading etf price data into matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

I am a new R programmer and am trying to create a matrix of ETF prices by day.  Here is the code I am using:

```
#Download Packages
library(tseries)
library(quantmod)
#Setup list of symbols to download prices
pr=c("vti","vv","vug","vtv","vo")     
#get dates to download data
today=as.Date(Sys.Date())
yday=today-1
#set up matrix to hold data
pri=matrix(nrow=10,ncol=5)
for(i in 1:10){
for(j in 1:5) {
  pri[i,j]=get.hist.quote(instrument=pr[j],start=yday,quote="AdjClose",provider="yahoo",compression="d")
}
yday=yday-1}
  write(pri,"ETFData13115.ods",ncolumns=5,nrows=10,append=TRUE,sep="\t")
```

Here is the output and error message I'm getting:

```
Error in pri[i, j] = get.hist.quote(instrument = pr[j], start = yday,  : 
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
>   write(pri,"ETFData13115.ods",ncolumns=5,nrows=10,append=TRUE,sep="\t")
Error in write(pri, "ETFData13115.ods", ncolumns = 5, nrows = 10, append = TRUE,  : 
  unused argument (nrows = 10)
> print(pri)
       [,1] [,2]  [,3]  [,4]   [,5]
 [1,] 103.1 91.6 102.8 81.03 121.08
 [2,]    NA   NA    NA    NA     NA
 [3,]    NA   NA    NA    NA     NA
 [4,]    NA   NA    NA    NA     NA
 [5,]    NA   NA    NA    NA     NA
 [6,]    NA   NA    NA    NA     NA
 [7,]    NA   NA    NA    NA     NA
 [8,]    NA   NA    NA    NA     NA
 [9,]    NA   NA    NA    NA     NA
[10,]    NA   NA    NA    NA     NA
```

What am I doing wrong?
Is there an easier way to assemble my matrix?

Thanks for any help.
Robert S

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the assignment operator:

```
pri[i,j] <- get.hist.quote(...)
```

UPDATE:

When attempting

```
a <- get.hist.quote( instrument=pr[j], start=yday,quote="AdjClose",provider="yahoo",compression="d" )
```

We can see that `a` is not scalar:

```
> dim(a)
[1] 2 1

> a[1,1]
2015-01-29 
    104.52 
> a[2,1]
2015-01-30 
     103.1
```

So, you'll probably need to choose the data you want or rework your matrix to accommodate both.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that, replaced all "=" signs with "<-" signs, but got the same error. Any other thpoughts?

Comment: Ken- Thanks! Very strange, when I print out those elements I get this: 
> pri[1,1]
[1] 103.1
> pri[1,2]
[1] 91.6
> pri[2,1]
[1] NA        So, I'm not sure what is going on. Thanks for your suggestion though. -RS

Answer (score 0):

Updated with an actual solution.

Quantmod does a lot of what you're doing here for you already. You mainly just need the getSymbols command.

```
    #Download Packages
library(tseries)
library(quantmod)

#Your code is commented out line by line

#Setup list of symbols to download prices
    #pr=c("vti","vv","vug","vtv","vo")  

pr <- c("vti", "vv", "vug", "vtv", "vo")  #spaces are your friend

#you do not need to worry about which dates to select... explained in a second 
#get dates to download data
    #today=as.Date(Sys.Date())
    #yday=today-1
#set up matrix to hold data

#you do not need to do this, quantmod does it for you
    #pri=matrix(nrow=10,ncol=5)


#you definitely dont need the uter loop loop!
#for(i in 1:10){
#for(j in 1:5) {
  #get.hist.quote(instrument=pr[j],start=yday,quote="AdjClose",provider="yahoo",#compression="d")
#}

#this command gets all the data you want and assigns them to a data frame with ticker symbol
getSymbols(pr)

print(VTI[1:2]) #print the last 2 trading days of VTI, note this works even if yesterday was a weekend!!!!!!!


#write data to individuals csv files 
#for(j in 1:5) {

write.csv(
    get(toupper(pr[i])), paste(pr[i],"historical-quotes.csv", sep='-'))

}
  write(pri,"ETFData13115.ods",ncolumns=5,nrows=10,append=TRUE,sep="\t")
```

yday=today-1 Is not good usage for financial data since not all days are trading days. You should consider creating a vector of acceptable trading days and then selecting from that vector.

Comment: That's a good idea, I'll probably do that on the next go-round, but I don't think that caused the error message as the day selected for the second  iteration of the outer loop was a trading day. Any ideas as to what caused the message? Thanks, Robert S